# Constructing spatial weight matrix from triangulation of point coordinates in R?

Tags: r, point

I want to know how to construct spatial weight matrix from point coordinates in R,such as using the Lucas County, OH, housing point data set in `spdep` package.

I read [here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1690577),it says'the list of neighbours provided with the data set in spdep is a sphere of influence
graph constructed from a triangulation of the point coordinates of the houses
after projection to the Ohio North NAD83 (HARN) Lambert Conformal Conical
specification (EPSG:2834).'

I only know how to construct spatial weight matrix from polygons,no idea about points.

There is my code:

```
library(spdep)
library(rgdal)
data(house)
writeOGR(obj=house, dsn="test", layer="house", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
temp=readOGR("./test/house.shp")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a small sample of the house data for illustration:

```
> set.seed(123)
> h = house[sample(25357,100),]
```

Then you can use the `deldir` function to construct a Delaunay Triangulation:

```
> library(deldir) # install from CRAN if not got already
> hd = deldir(data.frame(coordinates(h)))
```

One element of this looks like this:

```
> head(hd$delsgs)
        x1       y1       x2       y2 ind1 ind2
1 507012.1 212861.7 484643.3 197553.9    6   74
2 505668.7 212737.6 507012.1 212861.7   18    6
3 506340.4 212874.5 507012.1 212861.7   51    6
4 506340.4 212874.5 505668.7 212737.6   51   18
5 503051.5 210910.0 484643.3 197553.9   35   74
6 503051.5 210910.0 507012.1 212861.7   35    6
```

and each row of `ind1` and `ind2` values represents a line in the triangulation, connecting the two points. So point 6 is connected to point 74, point 18 to point 6 and so on. This is an *adjacency list*.

You could go on to then construct the spatial weight matrix from those columns, but there's a function in `spdep` that does that for you:

```
> nbl = tri2nb(coordinates(h))
> nbl
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 100 
Number of nonzero links: 576 
Percentage nonzero weights: 5.76 
Average number of links: 5.76 
> plot(nbl,coordinates(h))
```

[image]

this is now a standard object that can be manipulated into the various spatial weight structures that `spdep` functions use.

Note this is only one of many ways of making a spatial weight matrix for point data, including N-Nearest neighbour, all neighbours within distance threshold, etc. Most of these are implemented in the `spdep` package.

Comment: So there is no need to export point data to shapefile.I used `nb2listw` and `listw2mat` function in ·spdep· package to get what I want.Thank you very much for your patience.